# Robot controller code: Error when loading

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I had written a simple serial controller using serial--actually, it is more Frankstein code, pieces others have written and I pieced together.  Feel free to poke fun at my ineptness, but any direction would be appreciated.  It runs fine on my Linux running Backtrack, Python 2.6, but when I try to run it on the Raspberry Pi, Python 2.7, I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Zombie Python 1.2 (Modified for Pi) (from Adapt 1.7).py", line 147, in rx
    self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1, bytesize=8, stopbits=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 276, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

File "/home/pi/Zombie Python 1.2 (Modified for Pi) (from Adapt 1.7).py", line 185, in <module>
    client = ThreadedClient(root)
  File "/home/pi/Zombie Python 1.2 (Modified for Pi) (from Adapt 1.7).py", line 113, in __init__
    self.periodicCall()
  File "/home/pi/Zombie Python 1.2 (Modified for Pi) (from Adapt 1.7).py", line 119, in periodicCall
    self.gui.processIncoming()
AttributeError: GuiPart instance has no attribute 'processIncoming'
```

My code is:

```
import Tkinter
import time
import threading
import random
import Queue
import serial
import readline
#import xbee
import sys

x=""

class GuiPart:
    def __init__(self, master, queue, endApplication):
       self.sonar = Tkinter.StringVar() # Feeds sonar sensor data to label       
       self.lm = Tkinter.StringVar()    # Feeds left motor speed to label    
       self.rm = Tkinter.StringVar()    # Feeds right motor speed to label      


       self.queue = queue
       # Set up the GUI
       frame1 = Tkinter.Frame(master, bd=200) #Setup frame.
       frame1.bind("<Key>", key) # Allow frame to handle keypresses.
       frame1.focus_set() #Set focus of frame so that keypresses activate event.
       frame1.pack() #Show it.

       #Button
       console = Tkinter.Button(frame1, text='Close', command=endApplication)
       console.pack()

       # Add more GUI stuff here
       self.lm.set(0) # Initializes left motor label
       self.rm.set(0) # Initializes right motor label
       self.sonar.set(0) # Initializes sonar label 

       #Sonar label
       sonarLbl = Tkinter.Label(frame1, textvariable=self.sonar)
       sonarLbl.pack()

       #Right motor label
       rmLbl = Tkinter.Label(frame1, text="Left Motor Speed: ", textvariable=self.rm)
       rmLbl.pack()

       #Left motor label
       lmLbl = Tkinter.Label(frame1, textvariable=self.lm)
       lmLbl.pack()


def key(self, event):
       #print "pressed", repr(event.char)  
       #self.sonar = repr(event.char) <------ This should be the line to handle keypresses
       global x    
       x = repr(event.char)

def processIncoming(self):
       """
       Handle all the messages currently in the queue (if any).
       """
       while self.queue.qsize():
           try:
               msg = self.queue.get(0)
               # Check contents of message and do what it says
               # As a test, we simply print it

           # Below is where I will parse the "msg" variable, splitting 
           # it (msg.rsplit) to pull out sensor data and update labels.

               lm, rm, sonar, mknt = msg.rsplit(",")
               lm = "Left Motor Speed: "+lm
               rm = "Right Motor Speed: "+rm
               sonar = "Sonar: "+sonar+" CMs away"

               self.sonar.set(sonar) # Setting the labels with latest sensor info.
               self.lm.set(lm) # Setting the labels with latest sensor info.
               self.rm.set(rm) # Setting the labels with latest sensor info.

           except Queue.Empty:
                pass

class ThreadedClient:
    """
    Launch the main part of the GUI and the worker thread. periodicCall and
    endApplication could reside in the GUI part, but putting them here
    means that you have all the thread controls in a single place.
    """
    def __init__(self, master):
        """
        Start the GUI and the asynchronous threads. We are in the main
        (original) thread of the application, which will later be used by
        the GUI. We spawn a new thread for the worker.
        """
        self.master = master

        # Create the queue
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()

        # Set up the GUI part
        self.gui = GuiPart(master, self.queue, self.endApplication)

        # Set up the thread to do asynchronous I/O
        # More can be made if necessary
        self.running = 1

        self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.workerThread1)
        self.thread1.start()

        #Start receiving thread.    
        self.rx = threading.Thread(target=self.rx)
        self.rx.start()

        # Start the periodic call in the GUI to check if the queue contains
        # anything
        self.periodicCall()

    def periodicCall(self):
        """
        Check every 100 ms if there is something new in the queue.
        """
        self.gui.processIncoming()
        if not self.running:
            # This is the brutal stop of the system. You may want to do
            # some cleanup before actually shutting it down.
            import sys
            sys.exit(1)
        self.master.after(100, self.periodicCall)

    def workerThread1(self):
        """
        This is where we handle the asynchronous I/O. For example, it may be
        a 'select()'.
        One important thing to remember is that the thread has to yield
        control.
        """
        while self.running:
            # To simulate asynchronous I/O, we create a random number at
            # random intervals. Replace the following 2 lines with the real
            # thing.
            time.sleep(rand.random() * 0.3)
            msg = rand.random()

        #self.queue.put(msg)


    # Continuously read and print packets
    def rx(self):
        global x
        self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1, bytesize=8, stopbits=1)
        self.ser.flush()
        while(1):
            response = str(self.ser.readline())

            # Send movement codes.      
            if x == "'a'" or x == "'A'": # or "'A'": # Turn left.
             self.ser.write('4')
            elif x == "'w'" or x == "'W'": #Go forward.
             self.ser.write("3")
            elif x == "'d'" or x == "'D'": #Turn right.
             self.ser.write("2")
            elif x == "'s'" or x == "'S'": #Go back.
             self.ser.write("1")
            elif x == "'x'" or x == "'X'": #Stop.
             self.ser.write("5")
            elif x == "'1'": #Raise speed.
             self.ser.write("7")
            elif x == "'2'": #Lower speed.
             self.ser.write("6")

            x = ""

            if len(response) > 10:
                self.ser.flushInput() #If you don't flush the buffer, then it'll try to read out all 
                                 #the sensor readings, so the reaction time will be extrordinary.
                time.sleep(.1)# This scales back the CPU usage.
                self.queue.put(response)

    def endApplication(self):
        print "Closing"
        self.running = 0
        self.ser.close()    
        sys.exit(1)

rand = random.Random()
root = Tkinter.Tk()

client = ThreadedClient(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `self.gui` is `GuiPart`. `GuiPart` doesn't have `processIncoming`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet displayed above the lines

```
def key(self, event):
```

and

```
def processIncoming(self):
```

are **no longer** indented by four blank spaces as they probably should to become methods of your class `GuiPart`.

Python newcomers coming from other languages often miss the detail that indentation is a very important part of the syntax in the Python programming language.  Therefore it is also very essential to avoid mixing TABs and spaces.
(Especially when copying code snippets from various sources which is otherwise
a great opportunity to learn and experiment with new things)

Another thing is: In Python you can also define module level global functions.
The syntax to do this is practically the same as the syntax used to define a method within a class (with the exception of the indentation level).

So in your example code snippet the former methods `key()` and `processIncoming()` had become module global function definitions instead of methods simply by wrong indentation.

A method is an attribute of a class object.  These two methods were moved
from the class name space one level up to module name space.
Hence the following error message:

```
AttributeError: GuiPart instance has no attribute 'processIncoming'
```